# How to insert multiple objects in sorted C# List by order, when I got CompareTo()

Tags: c#, list, sorting, insert, compareto

My homework task: I got Generic list in C#, I sorted it with `List.Sort` when `CompareTo()` is implemented. I have another list of same structure objects and I need to insert them in my first sorted List, not add them to the end of list and the again `List.Sort`, but Insert instantly in sorted and have sorted list after inserting. How should I do that? 
Long story short: I can't use SortedList, just Generic List, and I can't add my items to the end of MyList1 and then MyList1.Sort()
My Lists look like:

```
List<MyClass> MyList1 = new List<MyClass>():
List<MyClass> MyList2 = new List<MyClass>()
MyList1.Sort();
```

And I need items from `MyList2` insert into `MyList1` by the same order it is sorted.
My `CompareTo()` method, it sorts by two properties :

```
public int CompareTo(MyClass next)
{
    int pos = String.Compare(this.name, next.name, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    if ((this.price < next.price) || ((this.price== next.price) 
         && (pos > 0)))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        return - 1;
    }
}
```

I figured out how it should look like, this works fine:

```
static void Inserting(List<MyClass> List1,
           List<MyClass> List2)
        {

            foreach (var item in List2)
            {
                var i = 0;
                while (i < List1.Count && item.CompareTo(List1[i]) > 0)
                    i++;
                List1.Insert(i, item);
            }

        }
```

Comment: How big are the lists? If not big just first add and then sort. If big then you could binary search the correct index in which to place each new item and then use `Insert` with that index

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#orderedmerge or (more likely) https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#sortedmerge may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert it at the correct position, you have three options:

1. *find* the correct position, then `Insert` it there
2. use a pre-sorted list such as `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` or `SortedSet<T>` (depending on your needs) and just *add* (note: `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` demands unique keys; `SortedSet<T>` applies unique values)
3. just `AddRange()` the second list and call `Sort()` again

<strike>The problem with "1" is that finding the correct position for each new element *efficiently* is awkward. If this were an array, you could use `Array.BinarySearch` - it returns a bitwise complement of the appropriate index if no match is found. You could *implement* a binary search on a `List<T>` manually, but.. that's not fun.</strike> For 1, you'd want to use `BinarySearch` which exists on the list (thanks @mjwills), noting that the return value when no match is found is a bitwise complement that tells you where to insert it. But you'll still need to do this for each element, which adds up.

Personally, I'd be tempted by `SortedSet<T>` or just calling `AddRange()` + `Sort()` on a `List<T>`

Comment: I can not use SortedList or Add all items to the end of the list and then sort them, I need them to be inserted in the right place instant. I prefer your 1 option, but I don't know how to do it, when I have not one item to add but a couple of them.

Comment: @GoodnightJess "I need them to be inserted in the right place instant" - can you clarify *why* that is? if you explain *why* you can't just append and re-sort, you'll probably get better answers. But: if you know how to do it for *one element*, then the approach for *multiple* elements is just `foreach(var item in newItems) DoTheThing(item);`

Comment: Everything is because of my specific task, I can not use anything else, I already did add and sort them then, but task giver said no, no. But I already did it with foreach(var item in newItems), it works fine, thanks.

Comment: @GoodnightJess the only reason I can assume there is: atomicity - however, there is **no** atomic way to add items to a list, so... that by itself makes no sense. Tip: when somebody gives you a technical constraint, it is OK to ask for the reasons for that constraint. If this was me, I'd be asking "why?" - because the reasons "why" absolutely 100% determine the appropriate ways of approaching the problem. For example, if the reasons are "performance" - the next questions are "how big is the list" and "what are the specific performance demands". It isn't sure that in-place insert is optimal.

Comment: @GoodnightJess and more so: with the edit, if performance is the concern, then your implementation adds an `O(NxM)`. I strongly suspect that `AddRange` plus a single `Sort()` might be *faster*

Comment: @MarcGravellThanks for your effort, I will keep that in mind and try to optimize this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the List Add method and do it like the below example

```
public class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Desc
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int CompareTo(MyClass other)
    {
        return Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
}

public class MyList<T> : List<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item)
    {          
        if (base.Count == 0)
        {
            base.Add(item);
            return;
        }
        if (base[base.Count - 1].CompareTo(item) <= 0)
        {
            base.Add(item);
            return;
        }
        if (base[0].CompareTo(item) >= 0)
        {
            base.Insert(0, item);
            return;
        }
        int index = base.BinarySearch(item);
        if (index < 0)
            index = ~index;
        base.Insert(index, item);
        base.Add(item);
    }
}


   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.Name = "B";
        MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
        myClass1.Name = "A";
        MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass();
        myClass2.Name = "C";
        MyClass myClass3 = new MyClass();
        myClass3.Name = "A";
        MyList<MyClass>mylist= new MyList<MyClass>();

        mylist.Add(myClass);
        mylist.Add(myClass1);
        mylist.Add(myClass2);
        mylist.Add(myClass3);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

mylist will always be sorted here.